# When was the first time Wonder Woman defeated Ares?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, wonder-woman

Wonder Woman has fought many battles with Ares (Mars), but which was the comic where she first encountered Ares and how she defeated him ?

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit, but `episode-identification` is the correct use for finding comics

Comment: @Edlothiad [episode-identification] should be used for questions where the exact series is known. In this case it isn't.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I thought it was used for finding a comic as well. Check meta.

Comment: @Edlothiad "which issue of _Trinity_ conains X?" <- that's [episode-identification]. "Which was the first issue where...?" - that's story identification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first time Ares (formerly known as Mars) fights Wonder Woman (albeit indirectly) is in [Wonder Woman Vol 1 #1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_1) from June, 1942.

[image: Wonder Woman Vol 1 #1 Ares fights WW]

Ares can be seen behind Wonder Woman's head, with the speech bubble. The next panel confirms Mars' (Ares') defeat to Wonder Woman. Where she beats them by using her lasso to tilt the space ship and knock them off.

[image: Wonder Woman Vol 1 #1 Ares admits defeat]

Finally, the first time Ares fights Wonder Woman proper, is in [Wonder Woman Vol 1 #5](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_5) from July, 1943

[image: Wonder Woman Vol 1 #5 Ares fights WW]

A fight which Wonder Woman wins by knock out.

[image: WW Vol 1 #5 Ares knocked out by WW]