# Has Wonder Woman ever been defeated by Ares?

Tags: dc, comics, wonder-woman

In Wonder Woman comics, has she ever been defeated by Ares, the God of war ?

Comment: Related: [When was the first time Wonder Woman defeated Ares?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154707/68872)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Injustice* Year One, #9, Ares overpowers her in a very brief encounter because he is fueled by all the conflict and destruction around.

[image]

This doesn't last long because right in the next panel Superman arrives and knocks Ares out with just one punch, and then Wonder Woman pins Ares to the ground with her sword.